# Inserting unicode symbol through glyph code in math

Tags: math-mode, unicode

I realise many similar questions have been made but, after two weeks googling the net and searching on this site without results, I too must ask about this.

I have a document, to compile in XeTeX, with the following preamble:

```
% Declaration

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage,fleqn]{report}

% Main Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% Text Fonts

\setmainfont[
    Path            =   /usr/share/fonts/google-noto/,
    BoldFont        =   NotoSerif-Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont      =   NotoSerif-Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont  =   NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
    ]{NotoSerif-Regular.ttf}

% Math Fonts

\setmathfont[
    Path            =   /usr/share/fonts/xits/,
    BoldFont        =   xits-mathbold.otf
    ]{xits-math.otf}

\setmathfont[
    Path            =   /usr/share/fonts/google-noto/,
    BoldFont        =   NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf,
    range           =   "0A80-"0AFF
    ]{NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf}
```

Now I want to insert a letter from the Gujarati range as a math symbol inside a mathematical expression.

If I wanted to do so in plain text, I could define I wanted to use the Gujarati language or, if I only wanted a sepecific letter as a symbol, I could (and did) do this:

```
\newfontfamily{\gujarati}[
    Path            =   /usr/share/fonts/google-noto/,
    BoldFont        =   NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf
    ]{NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf}

\newcommand{\ddha}{{\gujarati\symbol"0AA2}}
```

If I wanted to simply insert text in a math environment, I could use the command

```
\text{\gujarati\symbol"0AA2}
```

but that is not the same as using a math symbol.

In math I have tried using syntax based on

```
\DeclareMathOperator
\DeclareMathSymbol
\mathchar
\UnicodeMathSymbol
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

and many others, as I searched the net and this site, but with no success, either because they are overcomplicated or because they were not meant to recognize unicode glyph codes.

How, then, may I insert unicode glyph "0AA2 inside a math expression as a math symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+0AA2 is not a math symbol, so using `range` does not work. A simple way is to use `\textnormal`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Main Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % optional

% for Gujarati symbols
\newfontfamily{\gujarati}{FreeSerif}
\newcommand{\ddha}{\textnormal{\gujarati ^^^^0aa2}}
\newunicodechar{ઢ}{\ddha} % optional

\begin{document}

$a+\ddha+ઢ$

\end{document}
```

I minimized the code, choose the fonts you need. On the other hand, loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra` is not recommended any longer (actually, my recommendation is *not* to load them).

[image]

The lines marked “optional” allow you to directly use the character in formulas.

Comment: Worked perfectly, and the optional syntax solves a lot of problems. Thank you.