# citation problem biber/xelatex

Tags: xetex, biber

I'm using MikteX with TexStudio (3.1.1). I Cannot get my references with Biber. Here's what I have in preamble

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \usepackage{xltxtra}

    \usepackage{xunicode}

    \usepackage{polyglossia}

    \setdefaultlanguage{french}

    \bibliography{testa}

    \usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}

    \usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
```

The message I get from Biber is

> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
> INFO - Logfile is 'calme.blg'
> INFO - Reading 'calme.bcf'
> WARN - No data sources defined!
> Processus terminé normalement

I have a new computer and my problem is that I have no problem with the documents made on my former computer, but only with the new documents, even with the same bib file. I read [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154754#154754) but I had already typeset my editor to work with biber.

Any idea about where my problem comes from ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2` is equivalent to the shorter `style=verbose-trad2,`. I also don't think you would want to load `\usepackage{xltxtra}` or `\usepackage{xunicode}` in a new document (it is possible that your old document relies on commands provided by those packages, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558049/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532483/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531014/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512470/35864).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to issue `\bibliography{<bibfile>}` or `\addbibresource{<bibfile>.bib}` *after* you have loaded `biblatex`.

```
\bibliography{testa}
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
```

will not work, but

```
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testa.bib}
```

will (the latter also works with `\bibliography{testa}` instead of `\addbibresource{testa.bib}`, but `\addbibresource` is recommended).

Unfortunately, you do not get an error for this misuse of `\bibliography`, because the command is also defined by standard LaTeX. But when you call it, it has the wrong definition for `biblatex`. One more reason to use `\addbibresource`: It would have thrown an error in the wrong position.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you.